# How do I access ModelMap in a jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

How can an object be accessed from the ModelMap in jsp so that a method can be called on it? Currently I recieve this error:

```
Syntax error on token "$", delete this token
```

JSP

```
<body>
        <% MenuWriter m = ${data.menus} %>
        <%= m.getMenus()%>  
</body>
```

Java

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/dashboard.htm")
@SessionAttributes("data")
public class DashBoardController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getPage(ModelMap model) {
        String[] menus = { "user", "auth", "menu items", };
        String[] files = { "menu", "item", "files", };
        MenuWriter m = new MenuWriter(menus, files);
        model.addAttribute("menus", m);

        String[] atocs = { "array", "of", "String" };
        model.addAttribute("user_atocs", atocs);

        return "dashboard"; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `<% %>` syntax is deprecated, and shouldn't be used any more.

The equivalent in modern JSP of your JSP fragment would be:

```
<body>
   ${menus.menus}
</body>
```

Obviously, that looks confusing, so you may want to consider renaming parts of your model for clarity.

Also, your annotation

```
@SessionAttributes("data")
```

does nothing here, since you have no entry in the `ModelMap` with the key `data`. This is only useful if you want to keep the model data across the session, which it doesn't seem you need to here.

Comment: Wow ok, thanks very much, that's so much easier. The reason for the 'data' session attribute was that I thought 'menus' would be accessible by 'data.menus' because it didn't seem possible to create either multiple entries in @SessionAttributes, e.g. '@SessionAttributes("menus","anotherSessionVar")' or alternatively have multiple '@SessionAttributes' annotations. Any idea how this can be done?

Comment: @James: Try `@SessionAttributes({"menus","anotherSessionVar"})`

Answer (score 2):

`${varName}` notation can be used in jstl only, and never - in plain java code. `$` character has no special meaning in Java.

Try something like `pageContext.getAttribute("varName")` or `session.getAttribute("varName")` (don't remember how exactly it's done).

Comment: Your first statement is misleading. You mean to say JSP here, not JSTL.