# In a JSP scriptlet, how do you access a java.util.Date value passed from a Spring MVC ModelMap?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, jodatime

FooController.java:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/foo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public final String foo(HttpServletRequest request, ModelMap model)
{
    java.util.Date myDate = new java.util.Date();
    model.addAttribute("myDate", myDate);
    return "foo";
}
```

foo.jsp:

```
<%
    java.util.Date myUtilDate = (java.util.Date)request.getParameter("myDate");
    org.joda.time.DateTime myJodaDate = new org.joda.time.DateTime(myUtilDate);
%>

<joda:format value="${myJodaDate}" style="LL"/>
```

Why does the JSP scriptlet fail to obtain the `myDate` value that was added to the `ModelMap` in the `FooController`?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just access your ModelMap parameter with `${myDate}` - see similar questions: [How do I access ModelMap in a jsp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384080/how-do-i-access-modelmap-in-a-jsp) and [JSPs not displaying objects from model in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529184/jsps-not-displaying-objects-from-model-in-spring)

Comment: EL syntax (as you've described) is the "correct" way to access data stored in the model

Answer (score 1):

The attributes in the ModelMap are stored as request (or session, depending on your declarations) **attributes**, not parameters.
After your controller method finishes execution, Spring forwards to the JSP associated with the returned view name.

So, in your JSP, you must use `request.getAttribute("myDate")`, not `getParameter`.
Actually, you should stay away from Java code in JSPs, but you should also understand what EL expressions do - in your case, `${myDate}` finds the request attribute named "myDate".

P.S.: There is an existing tag in JSTL for formatting `java.util.Date`s based on patterns, `<fmt:formatDate>`.

Answer (score 0):

That's a request parameter, you need to bind appropriately coming off the wire, I wrote a blog post on this last week:

http://linkedjava.blogspot.com/2011/06/spring-controller-with-date-object.html

Answer (score 0):

Answer by Nicolae Albu is right - this is request **attribute**, not **parameter**.
Attribute is something you associate with request yourself, in code, using API (in this case - Spring MVC does that using Model). Parameters are added by Servlet Container, not you, and they represent URL/POST parameters sent by browser.

The only thing to add is that ${varName} is equivalent to pageContext.findAttribute("varName");
and request.getAttribute("varName") is equivalent to pageContext.getAttribute("varName", PageContext.REQUEST_SCOPE) (if you're not sure what this is about, look up documentation on page, request, session and application scopes in Servlets+JSPs).